# Video and audio playback problems

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, audio, video

since I started my computer yesterday, I experience the following problems:

- in Chrome and Firefox, videos stop playing, lose sound or reset at
  random times (could be after a few seconds or several minutes). It
  happens with both Flash and Html5 videos, and on all sites (Youtube,
  IGN, Gamespot, etc.). I have to close and reopen the browser tab to
  be able to play the video again... then the same problems occur
  again.
- In Spotify, music stops playing randomly as well. Changing track
  doesn't fix the problem, I have to restart Spotify.

Here's what I have tried:

- restart the computer many times
- Uninstall / reinstall Flash
- Disable Flash in Chrome plugins
- Disable hardware acceleration in Flash
- Uninstall Camstudio, the only software I installed recently
- Run CCleaner and clear caches
- Try on Firefox (which is clean, I never use it), same problem
- Reinstall Chrome
- Reinstall Spotify

This is my work computer, running Windows 7 64 bit Enterprise SP1 and it has the latest Windows updates.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved by installing the Realtek HD audio driver. For some reason, only the default Microsoft audio driver was installed on this PC. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I've come to this issue myself and done some research. 
Some of the causes related to it:
 1. Video paused for some time and when resumed the video gets reloaded and starts from the moment you left it. (Usually happens on youtube)
 2. Lost connection - sometimes it might happen that you lose your internet connection, and the video gets "reloaded" at the moment it was interrupted. 
 3. Browser changes regarding HTML5 implementation. - I think this could your case. As I've had the same problem the latest months and not before. Some video players do not support HTML5 video, and browsers are tending to update their core to play HTML5 by default, which in my opinion it's not still perfected.
 4. Change in your public IP - Several time ago, my ISP was doing some changes in the public IP (how the ip was set to different users), and google and many other sites showed messages like connection not secure or something similar. 

Some question I have:
 1. Have you tried to connect to another network? And if so does the same happen?
 2. Does this happen in another machine or only in this one?
 3. Are you running any firewall, antivirus or different DNS?

Comment: Btw, in the latest update of firefox, you need to wait for the video to be loaded completely (sometimes) and after finished watching the video and hitting replay, there is no audio anymore. Then you need to reload the page to work as it should. It could be also from youtube as every page works different in different browsers.

Comment: Problem solved by installing the Realtek HD audio driver. For some reason, only the default Microsoft audio driver was installed on this PC. Cheers.

Comment: I see... There was an easier solution for your case. :D
 Mark your own answer as the solution as it will mark the question as solved.

Comment: Yep, but I can only do that in 2 days :P